# error on table creation using phpPgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to grapple with phpPgAdmin and am having difficulties. when trying to use the automated tool to create a table, I get the following error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" at character 96
In statement:
CREATE TABLE "public"."business_secondary_category" ("id" SERIAL, "primary_category_id" integer(10) DEFAULT NULL, "secondary_category" character varying(150) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id")) WITHOUT OIDS
```

This is how I set it up:

[image: screenshot of table creation]

I can't figure out what I've done wrong. [Link to character](http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/AWVkz/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking out the length specification for the primary_category_id column, postgresql doesn't support the type `integer(10)`, only `integer` (aka `int4`)